# JSON retrive fine but also have JSONException error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I try to save user phone number and random 4 digits in MySQL database with php. Everything is okay and both: phone number and random number are saved in my db and I can retrieve "SUCCESS" json detail. But also activity makes this toast "Error parsing JSON data.". I found this message in {catch (JSONException e)}..... I know forgot add something somewhere and I will be grateful if someone can help me.

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Context context;

public SignUpActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String phoneNumber = arg0[0];


    String link;
    String data;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;

    try {
        data = "?phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");

        link = "https://androidtest22.000webhostapp.com/bubble/signupbubble.php" + data;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String jsonStr = result;
    //Toast.makeText(context,jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
            if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points should be noted here:

1. Even if an exception is thrown, you are returning a String, so if there is an error you will try to convert the generated String to a JSON, which will throw the JSONException exception.
2. You are not closing the connection stream.
3. You are passing a context as a parameter, this is not a good practice since it is very easy to cause a memory leak, or something like a phantom object, use a custom interface instead.
4. If you have: `Unable to resolve host "androidtest22.000webhostapp.com": No address associated with hostname`. Check your WiFi connection and device connection.
5. Your webservice is returning a integer before the JSON, you can see [here](https://androidtest22.000webhostapp.com/bubble/signupbubble.php?phonenumber=9999999), this makes the parse impossible.

**Finally, code:**

*SignUpTask.java*

```
public class SignUpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG = SignUpTask.class.getSimpleName();

    private final OnResponse onResponse;

    public SignUpTask(final OnResponse onResponse) {
        this.onResponse = onResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... phones) {
        if (phones == null || phones.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must pass a phone to this task");
        }

        final String phone = phones[0];
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            final String url = "https://androidtest22.000webhostapp.com/bubble/signupbubble.php" +
                "?phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            return new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").next();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error - Phone Number: " + phone, e);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
            onResponse.onFailure(new RuntimeException("Invalid result"));
            return;
        }

        try {
            onResponse.onSuccess(new JSONObject(result));
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            onResponse.onFailure(e);
        }
    }

    public interface OnResponse {

        void onSuccess(JSONObject result);

        void onFailure(Throwable throwable);
    }
}
```

In your *YourActivity.java*

```
private void request() {
    new SignUpTask(new SignUpTask.OnResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final JSONObject result) {
            String queryResult = null;
            try {
                queryResult = result.getString("query_result");
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            }

            if ("SUCCESS".equals(queryResult)) {
                showToast("Data inserted successfully.");
            } else if ("FAILURE".equals(queryResult)) {
                showToast("Data could not be inserted.");
            } else {
                showToast("Couldn't connect to remote database.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", throwable);
            showToast("Couldn't get any JSON data.");
        }
    }).execute("999999999");
}

private void showToast(final String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what if try using new JSONObject(jsonStr.trim());

Answer (score 0):

It throws `JSONException` because it prints invalid JSON string. I've checked the URL : `https://androidtest22.000webhostapp.com/bubble/signupbubble.php?phonenumber=1265` and it shows an output of

```
83{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}
```

You must remove the number from the result. In the above case it's 83. Probably you forgot to remove the `echo` which you used while debugging the program.

SOLUTION : Remove the number from the result then retry.